# Summing/Grouping LAG() results in SQLite query

Tags: sqlite, window-functions, sqlite3

I have a table with incremental counters in an SQLite database. A stripped-down example would be:

```
PRAGMA foreign_keys=OFF;
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "counters"(date TEXT PRIMARY KEY, hours INT);
INSERT INTO counters VALUES('2022-09-25',10360);
INSERT INTO counters VALUES('2022-09-26',10368);
INSERT INTO counters VALUES('2022-09-27',10370);
INSERT INTO counters VALUES('2022-09-28',10374);
INSERT INTO counters VALUES('2022-09-29',10380);
INSERT INTO counters VALUES('2022-09-30',10387);
INSERT INTO counters VALUES('2022-10-01',10387);
INSERT INTO counters VALUES('2022-10-02',10390);
INSERT INTO counters VALUES('2022-10-03',10394);
INSERT INTO counters VALUES('2022-10-04',10399);
INSERT INTO counters VALUES('2022-10-05',10405);
COMMIT;
```

I can query the difference of the counter between two dates using the `LAG` function, e.g. like so:

```
SELECT
    STRFTIME('%Y-%m', DATE(date, 'localtime')),
    hours - LAG(hours, 1) OVER(ORDER BY date)
FROM counters
ORDER BY date
LIMIT -1 OFFSET 1;
```

Which gives me, for the above example, this:

```
2022-09|8
2022-09|2
2022-09|4
2022-09|6
2022-09|7
2022-10|0
2022-10|3
2022-10|4
2022-10|5
2022-10|6
```

But I'm struggling to sum up all those values, e.g. per month. If I do somthing like:

```
SELECT
    STRFTIME('%Y-%m', DATE(date, 'localtime')) AS month,
    SUM(hours - LAG(hours, 1) OVER(ORDER BY date)) AS hours
FROM counters
GROUP BY month
ORDER BY date
LIMIT -1 OFFSET 1;
```

I get

```
Parse error: misuse of window function LAG()
ATE(date, 'localtime')) AS month,     SUM(hours - LAG(hours, 1) OVER(ORDER BY 
                                    error here ---^
```

What's wrong? How can I do this?

Thanks for all help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use nested aggregate/window functions.

So use your 1st query as CTE, and aggregate it in outer query.

```sql
WITH
cte AS (
    SELECT STRFTIME('%Y-%m', DATE(date, 'localtime')) month,
           hours - LAG(hours, 1) OVER(ORDER BY date) hours
    FROM counters
    ORDER BY date
    LIMIT -1 OFFSET 1
)
SELECT
    month,
    SUM(hours) AS hours
FROM cte
GROUP BY month
ORDER BY month;
```

Comment: With the "LIMIT -1 OFFSET 1" clause palced into the WITH cte AS clause, it works. Thanks for the solution!